# How do I use native Facebook login for my app?

Tags: ios, facebook

How do I use the user's native Facebook login in my app?
When I try to authenticate, it loads a web view instead of using their native login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK will use Facebook's app to login if it is installed. A web view is used when the native app is not available. Take a look [here], it is fairly straightforward: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2#login-apicalls). Just be sure to check the prerequisites, as it is fairly easy to forget about setting up your app's .plist file.